# Android : Opening Crop Intent of Camera (after taking picture) kills the caller Activity/App in Nexus 7 & Moto G

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-activity, onrestoreinstancestate

I am facing a problem with native camera app in nexus 7 & moto G.
From app I am opening the camera intent & after taking the picture I am calling `com.android.camera.action.CROP` intent. But when I click on save button, it doesn't return to my activity/app.

I read that due to lack of memory, Android kills the activities that are not in foreground. So I am saving the state in `onSaveInstanceState`.

Following is piece of code:

Method called to take picture from camera:

```
public void takePictureFromCamera() {       
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String imageFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/picture.jpg";
        File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);       
        profilePicUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile); // convert path to Uri
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, profilePicUri);        
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
}
```

Method called for cropping:

```
private void doCrop(Intent intent2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        int size = list.size();

        if (size == 0) {
            Bundle extras = intent2.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                doneCapturingPhoto(photo);
                photo = null;
            }
            return;
        }
        Log.i(" doCrop ","profilePicUri : "+ profilePicUri);
        intent.setData(profilePicUri);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        if (size > 0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));         
            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_IMAGE);
        }
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent intent) {                
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA || requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY || requestCode == CROP_IMAGE) {
            try {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    switch (requestCode) {
                    case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                    case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
                        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
                            profilePicUri = intent.getData();                           
                        }
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                doCrop(intent);
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                        break;
                    case CROP_IMAGE:
                        try {
                            if (loadingDialog != null && loadingDialog.isShowing()) {
                                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ignore) {
                        }
                        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                        if (extras != null) {
                            Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                            doneCapturingPhoto(photo);
                            photo = null;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    if (loadingDialog != null && loadingDialog.isShowing()) {
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignore) {
                }
                CommonUtilities.showToast(this, "Please try again.");               
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }       
}
```

onSaveInstanceState & restore values on restore :

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {       
        if(null != outState && null != profilePicUri){
            outState.putString("profilePicUri", profilePicUri.toString());
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
        restoreValue(savedInstanceState);       
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);       
    }

    private void restoreValue(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("profilePicUri"))
        {
            profilePicUri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("profilePicUri"));
        }
    }
```

I have observed that most of the app that calls camera intent are having same problem in these (Moto G & Nexus 7) devices except **whatsapp**. I am not sure how they have handle this scenario.

Thank you.

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: Yes. In my case it is 3rd party library. But at some places in my app, event it kills the activity before cropping. I mean on opening camera, it kills my activity.

Comment: "In my case it is 3rd party library" -- no, it is not. You are invoking a random app on the device, hoping that it exists and does what you think it does. **Use a library**, such as the ones listed in my blog post.

Comment: @CommonsWare - A library worked for me.

Comment: in my case crop working when i captured image from camera but picking image from gallery that time getting toeast editing does not supported for this image